# Inequality in datastore query in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm implementing queries to datastore in Go, but the inequality operator is not working as expected.

Here's my code

```
query2 := datastore.NewQuery(MetaData)
if !hasAccess {
    for _, zone := range filters.Zones {
        query2 = query2.Filter("Zone <", zone)
        query2 = query2.Filter("Zone >", zone)
    }
}
```

The result always returns nil even though I have data in datastore that matches that criteria (Zone != zone).

Comment: per documentation you cant have more than one inequality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to effectively run two inequality filters on queries in app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021030/how-to-effectively-run-two-inequality-filters-on-queries-in-app-engine)